# OpenGL + multiple cameras

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Let me see if I understood. If I use multiple viewports I can create several "cameras" in my OpenGL application. Right?

Well, I have an object that can be seen in the viewport 1, but not visible in the viewport 2. If I want the subject appears in both viewports then ...I must draw double!

That means that if I have two objects, if I have two "cameras", I have to draw these objects twice. So everything I have in my scene, I must have to draw double.

Is this okay? Is there another way to split the screen without duplicating objects?

Comment: I think what you want is avoiding api call duplication. This could be done with viewport arrays if the target hw supports it. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewportArray.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this okay?

Yes, that's how it goes.

> Is there another way to split the screen without duplicating objects?

You're not duplicating objects. You can't because there's no such thing as an "object" in OpenGL. OpenGL is just a sophisticated kind of pencil to draw on a framebuffer. There is no scene, there are no objects, there are just points, lines and triangles drawn to a framebuffer.

All you do is draw several pictures of the same thing from different points of view, just as you'd like do it using a pencil on paper.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have a question, if I have a function that draws a model which performs various operations such computation of rotations, etc.. If I call this function for each viewport, I'm not doubling the number of operations for the same model?

Comment: yes you are doing it but the metaphor datenwolf got you is clear: it like draw with a pencil on paper. you want 2 paper in the end? you have to draw it twice, 2 points of view (2 cameras), 2 time computation cost.. maybe you can you object oriented programming to save some parameters and some calculus but it's up to your program, not opengl